# How can I open netrw in a split when opening a directory?

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows, netrw

I have figured out how to open a file browser in a split, using the following in vimrc:

```
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
let g:netrw_altv = 1
augroup ProjectDrawer
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore
augroup END
```

This is nice since I can then work with multiple files without having to exit and reopen vim all the time.

The issue is when I want to edit a specific file. Then I do not need or want the file browser.

So my question is: is there a way to wrap this in an if statement which would only open netrw in a split if the argument to `vi` is not a file:

1. `vi path/to/folder/` - Include
2. `vi path/to/folder` - Include
3. `vi` - Include
4. `vi path/to/folder/my_file` - Skip

Comment: Doesn't Vim already open netrw by default if you open a path to a directory? It does that for me anyway, without having to set anything up.

Comment: See `:help v:argv`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij My commands opens it in a left side pane, kinda like VSCode. So not the same.

Comment: Ah right; I edited the question a little bit to make that clearer.

Comment: @MartinTournoij But Christopher also wants netrw opened if no arguments are specified. I think your title edit obscures this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose the following code:

```
let s:hasfolder=1
let g:foldertoopen = '.'

function s:parse_arguments()
  let i = 1
  while i < len(v:argv)
    if v:argv[i][0] == '-'
      let i = i + 2
    else
      let path = v:argv[i]
      if path[len(path)-1] == '\' || path[len(path)-1] == '/'
        let path = path[:-2]
      endif
      if finddir(escape(fnamemodify(path, ':t'), ' '), escape(fnamemodify(path, ':h'), ' ')) != ''
        let s:hasfolder = 1
        let g:foldertoopen = v:argv[i]
        break
      else
        let s:hasfolder = 0
      endif
      let i = i + 1
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction

call s:parse_arguments()

let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
let g:netrw_altv = 1

function! InitBrowser()
  if g:foldertoopen != ''
    enew
    exe 'Vexplore ' . g:foldertoopen
    let g:foldertoopen = ''
  endif
endfunction

if s:hasfolder
  augroup ProjectDrawer
    autocmd!
     autocmd VimEnter * :call InitBrowser()
  augroup END
endif
```

Comment: You can break the while loop when you find a folder.

Comment: @Ben, You are right, I have been lazy ;-)

Comment: Just tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know enough about coding in vimrc (Vimscript it's called, right?) to debug it. Could be just a small thing. But now I have something to start with at least. Thx!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It works for me. On which OS are you using Vim? Which  version of Vim have you? You can insert `echom` trace to understand how the code is executed.

Comment: I noticed that case 3 us not supported yet. I'll do it tomorrow ;-)

Comment: @ChristofferReijer, I have prepared a new version. Maybe could you have a try.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I've marked it as accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I should have compared your solution with mine more carefully :-)